# cloud architecture best practice with grails

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, grails, architecture, cloud

I'm currently working on setup a cloud architecture based on Grails technology.

This my Architecture Diagram (ROA) :
[image]
In this architecture all apps (mobile apps or Web apps) have the similar behavior because they asking for ressources ( resource == model reflecting database table or many database table) by Web services.

As you see the foundation is one responsible for sharing ressources for the apps.
This architecture make me a problem when the number of request will be hudge.

I'm wondering if it's better to make an instance of the ressource for each application(for each application one database and instance of the foundation )  or share the same instance for all applications because, the applications have to share some ressources and I treat them seperatly I have to synchronize between them.

I'm really confused about this.
any suggestion ?